# a turn of mind is found in nature

Tags: phrase-meaning

what does the bolded phrase mean?

> If this turn of mind **were founded in nature**, such unhappy persons would be the more to be pitied.

source: the handsome and deformed leg by Benjamin Franklin

Comment: Reading the [passage](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/40236/40236-h/40236-h.htm#Essay16), that phrase seems to mean "innate" and Franklin goes on to say he thinks "this turn of mind" is a *learnt* behaviour and so not worthy of pity.

Comment: @WeatherVane  I think A LEO was just trying to mark that part of the quote.  I've edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your title says "found in nature" but the quote is "*founded* in nature".  "Found" in this case is not the past tense of "find" but rather a completely different verb:

> [**found**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/found) (v):  verb (used with object)
>
> 1. to set up or establish on a firm basis or for enduring existence:
>      *to found a new publishing company.*
> 2. to lay the lowest part of (a structure) on a firm base or ground:
>      *a house founded on solid rock.*
> 3. to base or ground (usually followed by on or upon):
>      *a story founded on fact.*
> 4. to provide a basis or ground for.

Here is the full context:

> In whatever Situation Men can be plac’d, they may find Conveniencies and Inconveniencies: In whatever Company, they may find Persons & Conversations more or less pleasing: At whatever Table they may meet with Meats and Drinks of better and worse Taste, Dishes better and worse dress’d: In whatever Climate they will find good and bad Weather: Under whatever Government, they may find good and bad Laws, and good and bad Administration of those Laws: In every Poem or Work of Genius, they may see Faults and Beauties: In almost every Face & every Person, they may discover fine Features and Defects, good & bad Qualities. Under these Circumstances, the two Sorts of People above-mention’d fix their Attention, those who are to be happy, on the Conveniencies of Things the pleasant Parts of Conversation, the well-dress’d & well-tasted Dishes, the Goodness of the Wines, the Fine Weather, &c. &c. &c. and enjoy all with Chearfulness. Those who are to be unhappy think and speak only of the contraries. Hence they are continually discontented themselves, and by their Remarks sour the Pleasures of Society, offend personally many People, and make themselves every where disagreeable.
>
> **If this Turn of Mind was founded in Nature, such unhappy Persons would be the more to be pitied.** But as the Disposition to criticise and be disgusted is perhaps taken up originally by Imitation, and unawares grown into a Habit, which tho’ at present strong, may nevertheless be cured ...

Please be aware this is archaic English from the 18th century.  If writing today Franklin would say something more like:

> In this world there are people who try to always be happy, and those who are determined to be *unhappy*.  If this unhappy mindset **was the result of some inborn or innate natural cause**, then we would have pity for them.